# Java: JComboBox -> ScrollBar - change color

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jscrollbar

I'm working on small application. I made a JComboBox, and I want to change the colours inside. I already changed colour for background, foreground, arrowButton, ... But I don't know how to change the colours for scrollBar inside.

```
comoBox = new JComboBox();    
comoBox.setName("currencyCombo");

DefaultComboBoxModel comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
comboModel.addElement("gagD");
comboModel.addElement("agg");
comboModel.addElement("EhgsY");
comboModel.addElement("CgafgY");
comboModel.addElement("CfadgY");
comboModel.addElement("Ggafg");
comboModel.addElement("Sgfsdg");
comboModel.addElement("Ugfasdg");
comboModel.addElement("fasfasf");
comoBox.setModel(comboModel);
comoBox.setOpaque(true);

UIManager.put( "ComboBox.disabledBackground", new java.awt.Color(32, 34, 41));
UIManager.put( "ComboBox.disabledForeground", new java.awt.Color(181, 181, 181));
UIManager.put( "ComboBox.background", new java.awt.Color(32, 34, 41));
UIManager.put( "ComboBox.foreground", new java.awt.Color(181, 181, 181));
UIManager.put( "ComboBox.selectionBackground", new java.awt.Color(181, 181, 181));
UIManager.put( "ComboBox.selectionForeground", new java.awt.Color(32, 34, 41));

   comoBox.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI(){
   @Override
   protected JButton createArrowButton() {
       JButton arrowButton = new BasicArrowButton( 
        BasicArrowButton.SOUTH,
        new java.awt.Color(32, 34, 41), 
        new java.awt.Color(181, 181, 181),
        new java.awt.Color(181, 181, 181),
        new java.awt.Color(32, 34, 41));
       arrowButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(32, 34, 41)));
       return arrowButton;
    }             
});
```

I tried this:

```
Object obejct = currencyCombo.getUI().getAccessibleChild(currencyCombo, 0);
              Component co = ((Container) obejct).getComponent(0) ;
                      if( co instanceof JScrollPane){
                            JScrollPane pane = (JScrollPane) co;        
                            Component[] components = pane.getComponents();
                            for (Component component : components) {
                                if(component instanceof JScrollBar)
                                {
                                    JScrollBar jsb = (JScrollBar) component;
                                    jsb.setBackground(Color.red);
                                    jsb.setForeground(Color.blue);
                                    jsb.setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI());
                                    jsb.updateUI();
                                }

                            }

                      }
```

Comment: What is the **progressBar inside**?

Comment: I doubt that there is a special key for a scrollbar inside a combobox, it’s more likely that it will just the same keys as any other scrollbar.

Comment: @Holger I know how to change background for classic scrollBar (I think when I make a new component JScrollBar, I can change the color), but I don't know, how I can get to scrollBar in comboBox. I tried this, but it doesn't work ..

Comment: I added a code to the end of my question

Comment: I was talking about things like calling `UIManager.put("ScrollBar.background", Color.DARK_GRAY);` which affects *all* scrollbars, regardless of being in a combo box or not. I thought you were aware of it as you use the similar technique for changing the combobox defaults. traversing the component’s child hierarchy doesn’t help as the scrollpane&list are not children of the combobox, but rather of the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Hej jakub, the following code will change the background of ScrollBar inside the ComboBox:

**EDIT:** You can access to the color of the Scrollbar in these ways:

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.thumbHighlight", Color...;         
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.thumbDarkShadow", Color...; 
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.highlight", Color...; 
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.trackHighlight", Color...;
```

Comment: So now it’s not a question, still, it’s clear that you never tried it yourself as that simply doesn’t work.

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how I can with this change color of scrollBar. Maybe if is there some function, that I can override, as I do it with arrowButton.

Comment: @jakub, I was finding more information,  In the next link explain how to change the size of ScrollBar inside a JComboBox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207127/change-the-size-of-a-scrollbar-in-jcombobox
Can you try to do same than there (except the Dimensions part because are related to size)and comment the results? After that you can try to change color of the ScrollBar in these ways:

`UIManager.put("ScrollBar.thumbHighlight", Color...;`
`UIManager.put("ScrollBar.thumbDarkShadow", Color...;`
`UIManager.put("ScrollBar.highlight", Color...;`

Comment: Now you are getting closer to a real answer. Finally you are doing real research… The only thing left to do is to remove that out-of-thin-air `"ComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackground"` property at the beginning of your answer…

Comment: @Holger thank you for the steps, after 2 weeks I am learning more of StackOverflow thanks for people like you!  Sorry before, if the answer was not appropriate.

Comment: Never mind. Just as a recommendation for the future, try your solution suggestions yourself instead of treating the questioner like a guinea pig (That’s the reason why questioners should provide self contained example code reproducing the problem; it allows answerers to test by themselves before posting a solution).

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense that it should work like that. Otherwise it could be catastrophic for getting the answers. I guess that what I did I am allowed to do it by comments. Is it?